# AngularJS HTML5 nested routes

Tags: html, url, angularjs

Angular: 1.1.5

I go to: `http://xxxxx.com/route1/route2/route3`
and `/route3` gets triggered instead of `route1/route2/route3`
Works fine with HTML5 mode off ... :(

Nginx config

```
location / {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}
```

My app config

```
$routeProvider.when('/route1/route2/route3', {
        templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });

$routeProvider.when('/route3', {
        templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });

$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

`$location` Log:

```
$$protocol: "http", $$host: "xxxxxx"…}
$$absUrl: "http://xxxxxxx.com/route1/route2/route3"
$$hash: ""
$$host: "10.44.11.73"
$$path: "/route3"
$$port: 80
$$protocol: "http"
$$replace: false
$$url: "/route3"
```

How can I change my settings to make HTML5 urls working with nested routes?

Answer (score 3):

For single page apps, this is all you need in your NGINX config:

```
server
{
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
    root /var/www/html/example;
    index index.html;
    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem...  
`$$absUrl: "http://www.locahost/route1/route2/route3"`  
`$$path: "/route3"`  
`$$url: "/route3"`  
path should be `/route1/route2/route3`

Comment: what is /var/www/html/example here? path to your web app?

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
<base href="/">
```

to your `index.html`.

Comment: That may help, but I'm not sure why.  What would that have to do with html5?